# How do i read from one text file and write to another file

Tags: php

I have a text file with phone numbers as follows:

7046382696  7046482666  70463826344

I want to write the numbers to a new file. I want each number written on a new line and with a zero before each number,  thus:

07046387666
07046382669
08046382693.

This is my script. It doesn't work at all:

```
  //Modify title to fit in url for Search Engine Optimization
function modified_for_new_line($data, $to_remove, $to_replace_with, $added_data)
{
  $data_splitter = explode($to_remove, $data);
  $data_packer = array_splice($data_splitter, 0);
  $modified_data = $added_data . implode($to_replace_with, $data_packer);
  return $modified_data;
}

$file1 = fopen("source.txt", "r");
$file2 = '#file2.txt';
if($file1)
{
  while(($line = fgets($file1)) !== false)
  {
    $the_line = modified_for_new_line($line, ' ', "\n", '');
    $new_line = 0 . $the_line;
    file_put_contents($file2, $new_line);
  }
  fclose($file1);
  fclose($file2);
  echo 'All iz well';
}
else {
      echo 'Sorry! There was a problem opening the file.';
}
```

Comment: Make sure you understand what `fopen`, `file_put_contents` for and how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$get_file = file_get_contents('file_url.php');
file_put_contents('your_new_file_name.php', $get_file);
?>
```

that code get file url and copy code and put It in your new file

Answer (score 1):

Using `file` to open the source file will give you an array, with each line being a member of the array so it is simple to then do a `foreach` on each member.

```
$source='/path/to/source.txt';
$target='/path/to/target.txt';

$lines=file( $source );
$data=array();

foreach( $lines as $line ){
    /* store each line with a leading zero into a temp array */
    $data[]='0' . trim( $line );
}

/* write the content back to another file */
file_put_contents( $target, implode( PHP_EOL, $data ) );
```